# Access to some websites constantly denied

Tags: blocked-services

Same problem as here: [why do I get "Access Denied" at certain web sites when I didn't last year?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6646/why-do-i-get-access-denied-at-certain-web-sites-when-i-didnt-last-year)

But: unfortunately the answer didn't help. The access to some sites is constantly denied even with using Vidalia to switch to a different identity and turning off NoScript 2.6.9.36.

using 5.0.3 on Tails 1.6

Edit: The subpages on one of the websites are accessible, well, at least they have been from time to time. So the website itself apparently does not block Tor nodes.

Comment: As you point out, your question is a duplicate, and could get closed as such. I added another answer to the question you link to. Basically, if you get the Reference #18.25b65bla.xxxetc... message, you can just not connect to that site from Tor.

Comment: This question, however, was never accepted - nor did it meet standards - in its other posting.  As a result, @Jobiwan, I posted a bounty and would appreciate a more canonical answer.